# JS script for drawing circles in Illustrator not aligning circle centers

Tags: javascript

I wrote a small script that takes in a csv file with this format:

```
x,y,s
0,0.5,30
0,0.6,50
0,0.8,80
```

and tries to draw a black circle in Illustrator based on the x and y coordinates, and the circle size is based on s. I'm pretty new to JS and scripting for Illustrator and can't for the life of me figure out why the circle centers are not vertically aligned:

[image]

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

The code snippet is this:

```
// Adobe Illustrator script to draw circles based on coordinates and diameter from a CSV file

// Function to read CSV file
function readCSV(filePath) {
    var file = File(filePath);
    file.open('r');
    var content = file.read();
    file.close();
    return content;
}

// Function to create a circle in Illustrator
function createCircle(x, y, diameterInPixels) {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    // Get the top left corner coordinates of the active artboard
    var xCoord = doc.artboards[doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()].artboardRect[0];
    var yCoord = doc.artboards[doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()].artboardRect[1];

    // Calculate the absolute coordinates
    var absoluteX = xCoord + x * doc.width;
    var absoluteY = yCoord - y * doc.height; // Adjusting for the Illustrator coordinate system

    // Convert the diameter from pixels to points
    var diameterInPoints = diameterInPixels;

    // Create a circle
    var circle = doc.activeLayer.pathItems.ellipse(absoluteX - diameterInPoints / 2, absoluteY - diameterInPoints / 2, diameterInPoints, diameterInPoints);

    // Set properties of the circle (black color)
    circle.fillColor = new RGBColor();
    circle.fillColor.red = 0;
    circle.fillColor.green = 0;
    circle.fillColor.blue = 0;

    circle.stroked = false; // No stroke for simplicity

    return circle; // Return the created circle
}

// Main script
var csvFilePath = 'path/to/file.csv'; // Replace with the actual path to the CSV file
var csvData = readCSV(csvFilePath);

if (csvData) {
    // Split the CSV data into rows
    var rows = csvData.split('\n');

    // Iterate through each row starting from the second row (skipping the header)
    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // Get the values from the current row
        var rowValues = rows[i].split(',');

        // Check if there are at least three values (x, y, and s)
        if (rowValues.length >= 3) {
            // Extract x, y, and diameter coordinates
            var xCoordinate = parseFloat(rowValues[0]);
            var yCoordinate = parseFloat(rowValues[1]);
            var diameter = parseFloat(rowValues[2]);

            // Check if the coordinates and diameter are valid numbers
            if (!isNaN(xCoordinate) && !isNaN(yCoordinate) && !isNaN(diameter)) {
                // Create a circle with the specified coordinates and diameter
                createCircle(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, diameter);
            } else {
                alert('Invalid coordinates or diameter in row ' + (i + 1) + ' of the CSV file.');
            }
        } else {
            alert('CSV file must have at least three columns: "x", "y", and "s".');
        }
    }
} else {
    alert('Error reading CSV file.');
}
```